# :not selector not working, removing classes aren't leaving...?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hover

I left images out but the functionality is there. I'm trying to:

1. once an li is clicked, apply some classes and append a word. (this works)
2. disable the hover effect on the currently selected item. (not working)
3. when a different li is clicked, restore to base then do step 1 and 2 with the newly selected li.

I've had pieces of this working at times. Via Firebug, the classes are all being added but I must not be selecting the correct way with multiple classes.

http://jsfiddle.net/thumbslinger/HbezN/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/HbezN/11/

Some tips:

- Don't use jQuery in place of CSS. Use CSS in place of CSS.
- Go easy on the class names. You'll get confused later on.

Comment: wow, that was fast! yes. I can't show who/where this is for but there are background graphics that make this much more complicated than the usual nav system. Big sprites or Flash would have much easier in this case! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/HbezN/13/
you need to remove the added `span` from `li` before removing the `current` class.

Comment: interesting...this works as well though I removed the hover function and used css as Blender suggested. What is the reasoning behind needing to remove the span first? Just wondering since the two approaches were different in this respect.

Comment: Because , here I select the previous selected li and remove the added span before removing it's class.